# The range of similarity in openAI text-embeddings is not [0, 1]

Tags: word-embedding, openai-api

I am using openAI Ada to create text-embeddings. When i calculate the similarity between these embeddings my answer is in the range [0.7, 0.9] approximately. In the rest of my project I would need these to be in [0.0, 1.0], and I want to find a way to normalize the values. Could I just normalize them based on the range [0.7, 0.9] or would that seem too risky as there is no real prove that that is actual the range?

I understand that just keeping them as they are might be the best way, but I would really benefit from having the very distanced sentences to be 0 and the really close one 1

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, many users on OpenAI forums are seeing the same thing (range of 0.7 - ~0.9 for cosine distance), and it is seeming like a "feature" of the ada embedding.

There are some potential solutions that go into the weeds here:
https://community.openai.com/t/embedding-results-scale-seems-off/278633